# Какая разница между SSH и SSL(HTTPS)?

Tags: ssh, ssl, https, шифрование, протоколы

Насколько я понимаю они оба шифруют данные. Какая разница каким сетевым протоколом пользоваться? Чем они отличаются ?

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` это `secure shell`(безопасная оболочка) благодаря ему можно удаленно подключаться к другой ПК защищенным образом и через оболочку осуществлять манипуляцию операционной системы(защищено) а `ssl` это протокол который осуществляет безопасную передачу данных(шифрованным образом) то есть создается безопасный канал передачи данных между двумя машинами.

Comment: SSH тоже позволяет создать безопасный канал данных, а внутри SSL/TLS тоже можно прокинуть какой-нибудь протокол для манипуляции операционной системой. Так в чём разница-то?

Comment: разница в CVE-2018-15473 для SSH (уязвимы все версии)

Comment: @misdeed всяких разных CVE у обоих хватает, так в чём разница-то)

Comment: @andreymal не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal Вот именно "_внутри SSL/TLS тоже можно прокинуть какой-нибудь протокол_". SSL это протокол сеансового уровня (OSI-5), он только обеспечивает шифрование канала. Его невозможно использовать сам по себе, для работы с ним необходим еще протокол прикладного (OSI-7) уровня. А SSH это готовый протокол OSI-7 с включенным в него же шифрованием.